# Paschen law in vacuum

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, vacuum

I did not find any article about it, Paschen's law works in a vacuum? (1e-6 Torr)? Or is the electric spark between two metals governed by the emission of the field effect of electrons?

Comment: Ultimately, yes, vacuum breakdown prevails.

Comment: @Jon Custer what is it that breaks down?

Comment: Electron and/or ion emission from surfaces.

Comment: @JonCuster That's not a breakdown of the insulating medium between the electrodes. A vacuum is not insulation

Comment: Actually, a vacuum with clean smooth surfaces is a very good insulator. To break down you need to get charged. With few gas molecules you need to get them from the surfaces. Roughness and absorbed species end up being a limit. Getting to ~100kv/cm isn’t too hard.

Comment: @JonCuster When I said not insulation I meant not insulating material. It's insulating material that electrically breaks down. That's all I have to say.

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335618/breakdown-voltage-in-vacuum

Comment: @BobD - well, vacuum has no free carriers and possesses a dielectric permittivity and does not react to having a field across it until free carriers are introduced in some fashion. The Paschen curve is one way, but if there are not sufficient gas molecules something else breaks. There is an entire field (power electronics, high energy accelerators, and pulsed power machines) that uses 'vacuum breakdown' as a technical term. If I told my designers that either vacuum is not an insulator, or that they don't have to worry about vacuum breakdown they would laugh at me.